# Cannot get data in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have code like this in my Laravel `index.blade` for showing the data from query list of product bundle:

```
<div class="kt-portlet">
    <div class="kt-portlet__body">
        <table id='table_product' class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed flip-content">
            <thead class="flip-content">
                <tr>
                    <th class="no-sort">Action</th>
                    <th class="">Name</th>
                    <th class="">Price</th>
                    @if (Auth::user()->is_super_admin)
                        <th class="no-sort">Hub</th>
                    @endif
                    <th class="">Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
@stop

@section('page_css')
<style type="text/css">
.old_price {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: line-through;
  font-style: italic;
}
</style>
@endsection

@section('add_js')
@parent
<script type="text/javascript">

    var table;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        {!! $form->printJs(); !!}

        $('#search_btn').click(function () {
            table.ajax.reload(function () {
                $('#search_btn').removeClass('kt-spinner kt-spinner--right kt-spinner--sm kt-spinner--light').attr('disabled', false);
                $('.no-sort').removeClass('sorting_asc');
            });
        });

        table = $("#table_product").DataTable({
            searchDelay: 500,
            filter: true,
            dom: `<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>
                        <'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-5'i><'col-sm-12 col-md-7 dataTables_pager'lp>>`,
            responsive: false,
            pageLength: 10,
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: {
              "url": "{{ URL::to('/') }}/product-bundle/data",
              "type": "POST",
              "headers": {
                  'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
              },
              "data": function (d) {
                  d.search = $('#global_search').val();
                  d.status = $('#status').val();
                  d.hub_id = $('#hub_id').val();
              }
            },
            columns: [{
                    data: "id"
                },
                {
                    data: "name"
                },
                {
                    data: "price"
                },
             @if (Auth::user()->is_super_admin)
                {
                data: "hub.name"
                },
                        @endif
                {
                    data: "status"
                }],
            columnDefs: [
                {
                    targets: 0,
                    orderable: false,
                    render: function (data, type, row) {
                        return '<a href="/product-bundle/' + row['id'] + '" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info btn-pill">DETAIL ...</a>';
                    }
                },
                {
                    targets: -1,
                    render: function (data, type, row) {
                        if (row['status'] == '1') {
                            return  'Active'
                        }
                        return 'Inactive'
                    }
                },
                {
                    "targets": 'no-sort',
                    "orderable": false,
                },
                {
                    targets: 'hidden',
                    visible: false,
                }
            ],
            "initComplete": function (settings, json) {
                $('.no-sort').removeClass('sorting_asc');
                table.columns.adjust().draw();
                $('.no-sort').removeClass('sorting_asc')
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

But when I see in my apps, I got error like my apps cannot get the value from `hub.name`, like my `hub.name` is "". So I cannot get the value of `hub.name`. In my models I have set `hub_id` as. When I inspect I got error like this:

> DataTables warning: table id=table_product - Requested unknown parameter 'hub.name' for row 0, column 3. For more information about this error, please see

```
public function hub()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Hub', 'hub_id')->select(['id', 'name', 'is_3rd_party']);
}
```

And here my repository:

```
public function list($limit = 10, $page = 1, $sort = "", $q = "", $params_extra = []) {
    $query = ProductBundle::select();
    $query->with('product_bundle_detail.product');
    $query->with('hub');
    if (!empty($params_extra)) {
        $query->where($params_extra);
    }
    $total = $query->count();

    if ($q != "") {
        $query->where(function ($query) use ($q) {
            return $query->where('name', 'like', "%$q%");
        });
    }
    if ($sort != "") {
        $sort = explode(':', $sort);
        $query->orderBy($sort[0],@$sort[1]);
    }
    $total_filtered = $query->count();
    $limit = ($limit == -1) ? 10 : $limit;
    if (!is_null($limit)) {
        $offset = ($page - 1) * $limit;
        $query->offset($offset)->limit($limit);
    }
    $data = $query->get()->map(function($value){
        $value = General::encode_ids($value->toArray());
        $value['images'] = json_decode($value['images']);
        $value['images_thumb'] = json_decode($value['images_thumb']);
        if (@$value['product_bundle_detail']) {
            foreach ($value['product_bundle_detail'] as $key1 => $product_bundle_detail) {
                if (@$product_bundle_detail['product']['images']) {
                    $value['product_bundle_detail'][$key1]['product']['images'] = json_decode($value['product_bundle_detail'][$key1]['product']['images']);
                }
            }
        }
        return $value;
    });
    return [
        'data' => $data,
        'total_rows' => $total,
        'total_filtered' => $total_filtered,
    ];
}
```

I have try to search where is the code error, But I cannot see where is the problem. Can anyone help me for fix this issue?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  What debugging have you tried? Does your relation really work with the `select()` included like that?  Is `$total` > 0?  Why are you suppressing error msgs like `@$value`, `@$product_bundle_detail`?  Have you tried removing the `map()` and looking at the results of your query, just to check it is working? Break the problem into small steps, and test each step. 1) That relationship.

Answer (score 0):

When using php variables in jQuery/javaScript, you must enclose them in double curly braces like this.

```
{{hub->name}}
```